# How to get sample data from a table or a view in Aster Teradata without using order by?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, teradata, aster

I am trying to get sample data from a table in Aster `Teradata` using `order by` using the following code:

```
SELECT "col" 
FROM   (SELECT "col", 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER ( 
                   ORDER BY 1) AS RANK 
        FROM   "nisha_test"."test_table") a 
WHERE  rank <= 10000
```

I want to get random `10000` rows without using `order by`.

Comment: Is this really an Aster system, which release?

Comment: Yes, it is Aster only. Aster DB 6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the `LIMIT` keyword to get random values from a table or a view in Aster DB.

```
select * from "nisha_test"."test_table" limit 10000;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a sample you should use the built-in sample feature.

For Aster (or Vantage MLE, but with a slightly different syntax) there's a [RandomSample](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/JtLhZxnZVIJAs8pZG1VVfg/hw41NxVeE~KKiiw_1n3kXA) operator, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM RandomSample (
  ON (SELECT 1) PARTITION BY 1 -- dummy data, but needed
  InputTable ('nisha_test.test_table')
  NumSample ('10000')
)
```

For Teradata there's the [SAMPLE](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/b8dd8xEYJnxfsq4uFRrHQQ/hyfVBxhz8aKKK1HS77zXnA) clause, e.g.

```
select * 
from nisha_test.test_table 
SAMPLE 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `QUALIFY` clause in Teradata to remove the outer `SELECT`:

```sql
SELECT col
FROM nisha_test.test_table
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NULL) <= 10000
```

In Teradata, I think you can use a constant value in the `ORDER BY`.  You may even be able to exclude the `ORDER BY` altogether: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()`